# sending an email on command line: "550 aliases" error

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, email, raspbian

I am trying to send an e-mail from Linux command line by executing:

```
echo "this is a test" | mail -s Subject <email address>
```

The error I get is:

```
send-mail: RCPT TO:<email address> (550 aliases)
```

My `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` file is configured correctly, I am sure. What am I missing?

Comment: check your /etc/aliases for validity. run `newaliases` and check for errors.

Comment: Thanks Glenn! I have searched how to set aliases, in this was the hint that I needed!

Answer (score 4):

`RCPT TO:` is an SMTP client message, which tells the server that you're about to send a mail to the given email address; 550 is a possible reply to that message, indicating that the server is incapable of sending mail to that address. The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) defines it as follows:

```
550  Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (e.g., mailbox
   not found, no access, or command rejected for policy reasons)
```

It also says that servers should provide a more detailed message along with the 550 line. The `aliases` bit of your output is most likely that "more detailed message".

No, that isn't very detailed, but the only person who can fix that is your mail server administrator. How to proceed from here depends heavily on your situation:

- If you are the administrator of the mail server, check its configuration and logs;
- If you are not the administrator of the mail server, talk to whoever is and ask them why you can't send mail through their server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers that pointed to the solution:

I had to create entries in `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` for the logged on user using the following synatx:

```
root:me@domain.com
```

Then, the `echo "this is a test" | mail -s Subject <email address>` worked.